# How do I set the QComboBox width to fit the largest item?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, qcombobox

I have a `QComboBox` that I fill with `QString` using:

```
comboBox->addItem(someString);
```

When I start my GUI application the width of the `QComboBox` is always 70, even if the smallest item is much larger. How can I dynamically set the width of a `QComboBox`, for instance, to the largest `QString` within the `comboBox`?

Comment: Also, if you want to keep the combo box the same size, but expand the dropdown width to fit the longest string, you can set the minimum width of the view: `ui->sieveSizeComboBox->view()->setMinimumWidth(width);`

Answer (score 19):

Qt (4.6) online documentation has this to say about `QComboBox`:

```
enum    SizeAdjustPolicy  { AdjustToContents, AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow, AdjustToMinimumContentsLength, AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon }
```

I would suggest

1. ensuring the `SizeAdjustPolicy` is actually being used
2. setting the enum to `AdjustToContents`. As you mention a `.ui` file I suggest doing that in Designer. Normally there shouldn't be anything fancy in your constructor at all concerning things you do in Designer.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcombobox.html) the default `SizeAdjustPolicy` is `AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow` so perhaps you are showing it and then populating it?

Either populate it first before showing it or try setting the policy to `QComboBox::AdjustToContents`.

That is assuming you have the `QComboBox` in a suitable layout, eg. `QHBoxLayout`, so that the size hint/policy is actually being used.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution to only change the size of the dropdown menu of the combobox to fit the largest text, without changing the size of the combobox itself:

Suppose you have a combobox called `cb`:

C++:

```
width = cb->minimumSizeHint().width()
cb->view().setMinimumWidth(width)
```

PyQT :

```
width = cb.minimumSizeHint().width()
cb.view().setMinimumWidth(width)
```