# Qt widgets do not adjust correctly after font size change

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt4

In my app a user can increase/decrease the font size by calling a css file with the new size definitions, and updating the stylesheets. However, I have issues with some widgets after the size changes.

The first one is that QComboBox items are overlapping:

[image: img]

I tried to set the height of the items but it doesn't seem to work:

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Btw, if I add the command "color: red;" it does work. But the height doesn't.

The second one is that the drop-down of a QComboBox is not getting wider and the text is being cut

[image: img]

I have some more issues, but I hope your answer will help me with the rest of them.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Basically, in order for it to adjust to contents,  you need to set SizeAdjustPolicy  of your QComboBox to AdjustToContents, make sure it is inside a suitable layout so that the SizePolicy is used and provide enough space for it to resize. 
Check out this thread [How do I set the QComboBox width to fit the largest item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151798/how-do-i-set-the-qcombobox-width-to-fit-the-largest-item)